# mail.log not showing all sent emails

Tags: linux, logging, postfix-mta

I'm using postfix as my MTA.  Yesterday my server sent out a few hundred emails, but a few recipients did not get their messages.  I tried to look at my mail.log to find those emails only to discover that only a couple dozen 'sendings' were recorded.

I.E. I know for a fact that my server sent an email to x@y.com, but that sending is not recorded in my mail.log.

Do I have to configure postfix to do something or look in another log?

Comment: I also added the -v flag to my smtp entry in master.cf, and reloaded the configuration.  I still dont see sendings going into the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Swift configuration was pointing to an external smtp server.  I updated the config and everything started to get logged appropriately.

Oy.